# Is it safe to store database ids in HTML pages?

Tags: html

Recently I've been doing some front-end code using JQuery, AngularJS & AJAX. For server side coding I use Java, Spring.

**Question**: Is it safe to store database ids in HTML pages ? Eg: A business domain object HOUSE has an attribute named AIR_CONDITION. If a user wants to update the type of AIR_CONDITION via the UI is it safe to store the HOUSE_ID in the html which can be used to save the updated value of AIR_CONDITION in the database ?

eg: code

```
<form action="updateAirCondition?houseId=22">
  <input type="checkbox" name="central" value="central"> Central air condition
  <input type="checkbox" name="external" value="External" checked> External air condition
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Update: The server side Java Spring Security application will be highly secure and will not update a row in the database if the user is not authorized to do so. My only worry is SQL injection and no matter what it's always better to have server side things (service code or database) hidden from the user anyway.

Comment: Note the user can change it to whatever value they wish, meaning that they can update any row in the table they choose (which you probably don't want to do). If they should not be able to update any house then it's not safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue of preventing a user from updating a record when they don't have permissions to do so is somewhat independent of whether or not it's okay to expose a particular id. Even if you didn't expose the id in html, there are other ways to discover ids: brute force iteration, for instance. Relying on the secrecy of your primary key ids to enforce security is a classic failure pattern known as [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). You should have server side checks that prevent unauthorized updates. Check if the currently logged in user owns the record they are trying to update, for instance. Exposing primary keys in urls is generally fine. StackOverflow for example, has primary keys in question pages and user profile pages.

Comment: Great thanks. I've updated the question. The server side code is highly secured with Spring Security at domain level. I just wanted to know if exposing primary keys is a normal thing to do. Thanks you answer solved my query.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the best approach to this would be to just encrypt that id number and then decrypt it server side. That way a user can't alter it to affect other rows and you're not passing back end information to the user.